# Merging overlapping lines while preserving multiple attributes using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, fields-attributes, gps, overlapping-features, dissolve

I am using ArcGIS Pro and trying to work out a problem for a field project I've been a part of that goes a step beyond a simple dissolve or merge of overlapping lines. For context:

The project entails driving up and down long roads to spray invasive weeds. We track the patches as lines on the GPS and note the species and the level of infestation. In some areas, there are weeds on both sides of the road. In post-processing I've chosen to snap all the patch lines to the centreline of the road (I could do to the edges of the polygon of the road ROW, but this would be less exact as the GPS isn't fully accurate as to which side of the road I'm on, especially for small roads or trails). This, of course, means that any lines that are beside each other now overlap.

In terms of geometry, a simple dissolve would probably do. However, as sometimes the patches on either side of the road are of different severities of infestation, or even different species, I want to preserve the attributes and amalgamate them/select the highest level.

For example, if there is a "low" infestation on one side and a "high" on the other, I want the dissolved centreline to be "high." If there are different species present on either side, I want those to be placed in their respective fields (there are multiple fields for species, each species found gets entered into a field).

**My problem has to do with preserving the attributes of all lines that are dissolved.** I can clean the attributes up using a script afterwards, but to do so I need to be able to have the attributes of all lines preserved in the new feature. Don't mind if it's messy or creates a bunch of different fields or duplicate info, again this can be cleaned up with a script after. **I just don't know what tool(s) to use to dissolve the overlapping lines and preserve all attributes.**

Note this is a single feature class, not merging/joining two different features together.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Currently using ArcPro, but can also use ArcGIS 10.6 or QGIS if there's an easier way to solve this in either of those.

Comment: I’ve focused your question on ArcGIS Pro. If you also want to ask about ArcMap and QGIS then please do that in separate questions. That way you can tell us what you’ve tried and where you’re stuck in each without the Q&A becoming convoluted.

Comment: Dissolve using attribute.